# How can I solve a "base64 invalid characters" error?

Tags: c#, character-encoding, base64

When I m trying to convert the value1 to byte[] using the following code:

```
string value1 = "4rdHFh%2BHYoS8oLdVvbUzEVqB8Lvm7kSPnuwF0AAABYQ%3D";
byte[] value2 = Convert.FromBase64String(value1);
```

Ι received an error that the string contents invalid base-64 characters...

What's wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: You'll need to convert it back from its URL encoding first.  HttpUtility.UrlDecode() method.

Answer (score 19):

From [`Convert.FromBase64String`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.convert.frombase64string%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)

> s is composed of base 64 digits, white space characters, and trailing
>   padding characters. **The base 64 digits in ascending order from zero
>   are the uppercase characters 'A' to 'Z', lowercase characters 'a' to
>   'z', numerals '0' to '9', and the symbols '+' and '/'**.

`%` is not allowed in [`base64`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64) encoding.

Check out *The Base64 index table* from [`Wikipedia`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64)

```
Value   Char
0   A   16  Q   32  g   48  w
1   B   17  R   33  h   49  x
2   C   18  S   34  i   50  y
3   D   19  T   35  j   51  z
4   E   20  U   36  k   52  0
5   F   21  V   37  l   53  1
6   G   22  W   38  m   54  2
7   H   23  X   39  n   55  3
8   I   24  Y   40  o   56  4
9   J   25  Z   41  p   57  5
10  K   26  a   42  q   58  6
11  L   27  b   43  r   59  7
12  M   28  c   44  s   60  8
13  N   29  d   45  t   61  9
14  O   30  e   46  u   62  +
15  P   31  f   47  v   63  /
```

Answer (score 7):

%2B is a + sign URL Encoded
%3D is an = sign URL Encoded.

Your input string is actually.

```
4rdHFh+HYoS8oLdVvbUzEVqB8Lvm7kSPnuwF0AAABYQ=
```

Answer (score 6):

I had the same problem, but none of these answer helping me! so I ask my question here:
[How to encrypt strings that may have non-base 64 characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40406635/how-to-encrypt-strings-that-may-have-non-base-64-characters)
and @[luke-park](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1718554/luke-park) solve my problem.(all credits go to him) So long story short is:

We have to convert our `inputString` data into a byte array then convert that to   `bsae64`. Now our data is valid `base64` format and can encrypt it:

```
byte[] data = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(inputString);
string b64 = Convert.ToBase64String(data);
```

I hope this help others people with the same problem.

**PS:** There are Two Encryption Classes in my post, that are great to use them for encrypt/decrypt strings.

Comment: We want to decode from Base-64 String, you are explaining about converting to Base-64 string.

Answer (score 3):

The string contains invalid characters. In this case the `%` sign.

If you unescape `%2B` to "+" and `%3D` to "=", then the string will be accepted.

Answer (score 2):

I think the problem is with character `%`. It is not allowed in base64 string

According to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.convert.frombase64string.aspx)

```
public static byte[] FromBase64String(  string s)
```

> s is composed of base-64 digits, white-space characters, and trailing
>   padding characters. The base-64 digits in ascending order from zero
>   are the uppercase characters "A" to "Z", lowercase characters "a" to
>   "z", numerals "0" to "9", and the symbols "+" and "/".

Answer (score 0):

It's because of '%' char in the string. It's not allowed in base64. Where do you take this string from?

Comment: There's no '#' char in the string ;)